# Запустить функцию при нажатии кнопки на странице настроек в ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, acf

Нужно запустить функцию после того, как на страница Options в ACF была обновлена. Я формирую json файл, с некоторыми свединиями по сайтуб и при сохранении страницы options, надо запустить функцию скачки этого файла.
Функция, что должна быть запущена

```
function json_generator($array) {
$json_generator_status = get_field('json_generator', 'options');
if ($json_generator_status['value'] == 'true') {
    $file = "fields.json";
    $fp = fopen($file, "w+");
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($array));
    fclose($fp);
    file_force_download($file);
} else {
    return;
} }


function test(){
json_generator(site_layout_builder());
```

};

```
add_action('post_updated', 'test');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В самом плагине acf-option-page.php есть зацепки, в которых можно выполнить свой код, после обновления и проверки nonce, через

```
do_action('acf/save_post', 'options');
```

примеры использования: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-save_post/

и ЕСЛИ не после проверки записи а в целом:

```
do_action('acf/input/admin_head');
```

пример использования и описание:  https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-input-admin_head/

Comment: А как пкредать саму функцию для исполнения?

Comment: Там же в ссылках примеры. Реальные примеры. Событие исполняется либо по открытию страницы настроек, либо при сохранении. Вообще не привязывается к кнопкам, а именно к событию записи или открытия.

Comment: Но при записи зацепки, можно передать либо ID страницы, либо функцию.

Comment: Либо я Вас не понимаю, либо вы не понимаете как использовать возможности. В примерах есть как прицепиться к данному хуку. В первом случае, ID передаётся при вызове, при втором нет необходимости передавать. Просто пишите что надо, оно и срабатывает, а ID Вам нужен или нет я не знаю, всё зависит от того, что Вы собрались писать. У Вас вопрос, как прицепиться, на него я ответил.